# MvvmCross RecylerView nested list items

Tags: android-recyclerview, mvvmcross

I have used `MvvmCross` binding with `MvxRecyclerView` and it works great. Now I need to use it for **nested list** and I don't have much progress.

All of implementation/code is in `ViewModels` and my `activities` have just a few lines of code. Parent `MvxRecyclerView` and child `MvxRecyclerView` both are rendered but, controls in parent container are all missing (except `MvxRecyclerview`) , height of child container is short and ...

Looks like simple binding of Mvvm does not work as easy for list of list items. 
The only example I found was for for native android which is not applicable. I appreciate if anyone can post any code sample in this regards.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you want to use recyclerviews in a recyclerview, for your nested lists. This is not working really well and is just causing memory leaks as i learned by myself.

[MVVMCross Nested Recyclerview Out of Memory Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36790645/mvvmcross-nested-recyclerview-out-of-memory-issue)

Iam using now a property in my ViewModel which retrieves a flat hierarchy. So basically i take my categories and the childitems and make a single list out of them and then use a ItemTemplateSelector (https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/pull/200) which displays categories and childitems differently and shows the user a "nested list".

Comment: I am away form my city but I will try your solution when I'm back. Thanks for reply!